Saving data from a Manipulate's current state using a FormObject control
I would like to save a large set of data that has been computed within a Manipulate.
Here is a minimal example:
DynamicModule[
 {data = RandomReal[1, 10], toSave},
 Manipulate[data = data^2;
  If[save && u != <||>,
   toSave = <|"name" -> u["SavedName"], "Data" -> data|>;
    DumpSave[u["Description"] <> ".mx", toSave]; save = False];
  u,

  {u, FormObject[{"SavedName" -> "String", "Description" -> "String"}]},
  
  {{save, False}, {True, False}}
  ]
 ]

data is something that is computed (e.g., by other controls.  The user has to put identifying strings and then submit.  In this example, the user would have to use the save button to save the data.
There are a few things that I would like to improve:

Eliminate the "save" button.  One way to do this would be to have the Submit button trigger the DumpSave.  This would also eliminate the If in the body of the Manipulate.
If I can't trigger the save action upon submit--is there better way to have the data saved without the If in the Manipulate's body?  I would guess checking that If dynamically would be inefficient (??).


Related Question saving Manipulate data inside a notebook

@A.Kato.  I looked at that post.  It shows a way to save results into a manipulate, but not repeated results into their own DumpSave files. *Note: the example I gave is a MWE--I wish to do something similar in a Manipulate with a bunch more stuff inside.
